# Check textfield is empty in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to check whether my textfield is empty for validation purpose but i am getting an error message `cannot resolve method isEmpty`

This is my partial coding:

```
private void addMovie(){
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        if(getIntent().getExtras()== null){
            databaseHandler.insertRow(
                    mvidEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvtitleEditText.getText().toString(),
                    mvtypeEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvstoryEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvratingEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvlanguageEditText.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(mvruntimeEditText.getText().toString()));
            if (mvidEditText.isEmpty() || mvtitleEditText.matc) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }else {
            databaseHandler.updateRow(rowID,
                    mvidEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvtitleEditText.getText().toString(),
                    mvtypeEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvstoryEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvratingEditText.getText().toString(), 
                    mvlanguageEditText.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(mvruntimeEditText.getText().toString()));

        }
    }
```

Are there any ways to do this? I did some research from stack overflow too.Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632678/to-check-if-all-edittext-are-empty

Answer (score 2):

Now in new version getText() is not working directly so use only text
like this

```
 if (enter_name.text.toString().isEmpty()) {


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes, there is no method `isEmpty()` in `EditText` class. you should do like this-

```
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextRef.getText().toString())){
        ///.... your remaining code if the edittext is not empty
    }
```

Comment: I'd add that TextUtils.isEmpty() checks whether the Editable returned by getText() is both not null and not an empty String, therefore avoid calling toString() when using this method, as it may fail with a NPE

Comment: @Egor, you are right. I usually do myself as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mvidEditText.getText().length() == 0){}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following for checking empty value for edittext

```
mvidEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty();
```

where isEmpty returns true if length of  this string is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mvidEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){print message here}
```

Answer (score 0):

to check Edittext is empty

```
if(myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
```

Or use below function

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
  return editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```